# Search for multiple words in a string with partial matching POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently search for multiple words in a string like this:

```
select name from restaurant where regexp_split_to_array(lower(name), '\s+') @> array['bar', 'food'];
```

Which splits the string in an array like this:
The Food Bar = [the, food, bar]

But it only works if the full words are in the string. I want to get the same result if I use "ba" and "foo" for example. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Full text search may do the trick:

```
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', name) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'the:* | food:* | bar:*')
```

Comment: Is ranking the results possible?

Comment: @KevinWaterson [Should be.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING)